# How can I get last committed code in particular file in git bash

Tags: git, git-bash

I am working in android and I have a file named `MainActivity.class`
and I am `init` that project by using gitbash and I want to get the previous code of `MainActivity.class`

If I tried this then it will rollback all files to the previous code but I don't want that:

```
git checkout -f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using Android Studio then It will be lot easier to you.**
Just follow These Steps

1. In left side of your android studio editor you got a commit panel or you can press `ctrl + alt + z`.
2. Then you will see a dialog then choose the file you want to rollback.

this is example image when I pressed `ctrl + alt + z`

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am using Android Studio, And I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this following command -

```
git checkout commitIdOfPreviousCommit path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: And in case OP needs `commitIdOfPreviousCommit`, he should use `git log path/to/file.txt`, and pick one.